# Extract data from excel and create a custom CSV - ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am receiving excel files from our client and I need to create a csv file from them. My issue is that the values in the excel files do not match our standards to create the csv file just by copying it. I need to get the values and put them in the correct order while I'm creating the file. I read through the livedocs for CF but I couldn't find anything the worked.

I was thinking to create a struct and pull the data out in it and then create the csv file based on my struct but I haven't done anything like this before and I am not sure if it is even possible. I also thought of using listGetAt instead of the struct but still haven't tried it.

Anyone did something like this before? I'm trying to hardcode as less values as possible because I see this becoming a future problem if we get a second client with the same issue.

Update (I changed my code around a lot the past few days so this is what I have at the moment)

```
<cfset DataDirectory = "E:\testfolder\test.xlsx"> 

<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#DataDirectory#" excludeHeaderRow="true" headerrow="1"  query="queryData"> 

 <cfquery name="contact" datasource="#ds#">
        select ClientBrandID 
        from ClientBrands 
        where surveyReferralID IN
                                (select surveyReferralID from clientAdmin where username = '#res#')
     </cfquery>


    <cfscript>
        dataFile = structNew();
        StructInsert(datafile,"ClientBrandID",contact.ClientBrandID);
        StructInsert(datafile,"surveyType", queryData.surveyType);  
    </cfscript>
 <cfscript> 

    ///We need an absolute path, so get the current directory path. 
    theFile=  "E:\testfolder\NewTest.csv";
    //Create a new Excel spreadsheet object and add the query data. 
    theSheet = SpreadsheetNew("PatientData"); 

    SpreadsheetAddRow(theSheet, "ClientBrandID,SurveyType,Location,ClientContactID,FirstName,LastName,HomePhone,WorkPhone,CellPhone,Email"); <!---This is the header of the new CSV --->
    SpreadsheetAddRows(theSheet, "datafile.clientbrandid, datafile.surveytype"); <!--- This is my latest failed attempt. Tried to pass in data from my struct, probably the quotes are the issue but haven't tried it without them --->
</cfscript> 

<!--- Write the spreadsheet to a file, replacing any existing file. ---> 
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#theFile#" format="csv" name="theSheet" overwrite=true >
```

All of these operations will need to be in a cfloop in order to go through all of the files in my test folder. Right now I am hardcoding a single file to fix the issue at hand before I do anything else. Also, I am missing another loop in between that will need to go through all the values of the file. It should be something like `<cfloop query='queryData'>` which is the query that Im getting from cfspreadsheet.

Comment: so are you just saying that your columns are in a different order? are they in a different order every time? is this an application for you to use or the customer?

Comment: the incoming columns are in a different order than my application but they are the same every time. This is an internal application for my company to use

Comment: (Edit) Is the order the only issue or do you need to reformat the values as well? I assume you are using `cfspreadsheet` to read the input. But it would help to see your code so we know what you have tried.

Comment: I just need to change the order of the columns and also add extra values to the new csv file. I am updating my post now to show what I did so far.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what do you do with the csv file once it's created?

Comment: I have created an application which takes the csv file and splits its' data in 4 different db tables. Then my application takes over to send email, appointment reminders etc. Then I create a backup of the new csv somewhere on my server and the original file is getting deleted from the main drive. When Im dealing with big clients they usually have an IT department which send the data in the correct format but smaller companies they just send their data through email and usually in the wrong format

Comment: What are these "extra values"? Is there a single value you are adding to all rows OR are there multiple values that somehow need to be matched up with the data from the spreadsheet?

Comment: I need to add internal ID on the first row which I'm getting from the contact query. The contact query that I posted returns an ID.

Comment: I think it is simpler than you are thinking. Creating the csv is just a simple output of the queries. Take a look at the example in the second half of Travis' answer.

Comment: I just saw that. Thanks Leigh

Comment: Right, because a CSV is nothing more than a text file with lots of (evil) commas and a .csv extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make it accept any order but you'll still need to hard code the expected column headers into an array or something and considering it is just for your internal use I would just add the data back to the CSV in the order it's supposed to be in.  Last time I made a spreadsheet from a query I did it like this.  Perhaps it will help.

```
<cfscript>
    sMySpreadSheet = spreadsheetNew();
    column = 1;
    <!--- header row --->
    <!--- Remember what is expected from SpreadsheetSetCellValue --->
    <!--- SpreadsheetSetCellValue(spreadsheetObj, value, row, column) --->

    spreadsheetSetCellValue(sMySpreadSheet ,"First Name",1,column); column++;
    spreadsheetSetCellValue(sMySpreadSheet ,"Last Name",1,column); column++;
    spreadsheetSetCellValue(sMySpreadSheet ,"DOB",1,column); column++;
    spreadsheetSetCellValue(sMySpreadSheet ,"Phone Number",1,column); column++;
    spreadsheetSetCellValue(sMySpreadSheet ,"Number of Kids",1,column); column++;

    <!--- data rows --->
    <!--- if you're not using a header row with real titles you can just use the 
          default col_x 
          example: spreadsheetSetCellValue(sMySpreadSheet , queryData.col_1[q], q+1, column); column++; --->
    for(q=1; q LTE queryData.recordCount; q++){
        column = 1;
        spreadsheetSetCellValue(sMySpreadSheet , queryData.first[q], q+1, column); column++;
        spreadsheetSetCellValue(sMySpreadSheet , queryData.last[q], q+1, column); column++;
        spreadsheetSetCellValue(sMySpreadSheet , queryData.dob[q], q+1, column); column++;
        spreadsheetSetCellValue(sMySpreadSheet , queryData.phoneNumber[q], q+1, column); column++;
        spreadsheetSetCellValue(sMySpreadSheet , queryData.kidCount[q], q+1, column); 

    }
    <!--- make it purdy (optional) --->
    spreadsheetFormatRow(queryData, {fgcolor="light_cornflower_blue"},1);   
</cfscript>
```

If you want to simply add to a CSV you can do something like this (wrap your stuff in " if you have them qualified):

```
<cfsetting enableCFoutputOnly = "Yes">
<cfsaveContent variable = "myCSV">
<cfset newline = #chr(13)#&#chr(10)#>
<cfoutput>First Name,Last Name,DOB,Phone Number,Number of Kids#newline#</cfoutput>
  <cfoutput query="queryData">#queryData.first#,#queryData.last#,#queryData.dob#,#queryData.phoneNumber#,#kqueryData.idCount##newline#/cfoutput>
</cfsaveContent>
</cfsetting>
<cffile action = "append" file = "[your file]" output = "#myCSV#">
```

If cfsavecontent causes white spaces issues and cfsetting doesn't help, here is another alternative.

```
<cfset myCSV = "First Name,Last Name,DOB,Phone Number,Number of Kids#newline#">
<cfloop query="queryData">
  <cfset myCSV &= "#queryData.first#,#queryData.last#,#queryData.dob#,#queryData.phoneNumber#,#queryData.kidCount##newline#">
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I think the last part alone might fix my issue. I could just read the xls file and just hardcode it in a cfsavecontent. The first part is pretty good as well, just moving the columns around to the correct places. I'll try it now and will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful with cfsavecontent when used as @Travis described.  When I do stuff like that, it picks up carraige returns in the source code.

Comment: Good point, white space can screw up a CSV file. You don't have to use cfsavecontent, you can concatenate the string as well.

Comment: I have another issue now though. When I'm reading the query data, one of the columns always has a space in it. Any thoughts on how to get around it? It looks like this: `queryData.Client Type`. I have around 180 *.xls files I cannot just go in a edit it manually. Is there a work around?

Comment: at least qualify my fields if you're going to edit my post, @Dan. :p

Comment: @Dan from Docs `Although you do not have to specify the query name when you refer to a query column, you should use the query name as a prefix for best practices reasons. For example, if you specify the Emplist query in your cfoutput tag, you can refer to the Firstname column in the Emplist query as Firstname. However, using the query name as a prefix--Emplist.Firstname-- is preferred, and is in the following procedure.` http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=queryDB_3.html

Comment: It should, what are you experiencing?

Comment: @Crematorio - Do not forget the row number. It is required when using array notation  ie `queryName["Client Type"][rowNumber]`

Comment: @Leigh - I found one of your old replies to a similar issue and I fixed it. I used `culumnNames` and renamed the column with the funky name. Also `queryName["Client Type"][rowNumber]` was giving me some errors that's why I chose to use the columnNames

Comment: @Crematorio - Well associative array notation should work (even with the spaces). But perhaps there other things going on. So if renaming works, go with that :)

Comment: [rownumber] should probably have been [currentrow]

Comment: If it is inside a query loop, yes. But the `rowNumber` was just meant to be descriptive ie illustrate the general syntax ;)

Comment: We know that, but he might not. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions based on the edited question.  I'm making them even though the edited question does not make it clear what you are trying to achieve.

Regarding, "All of these operations will need to be in a cfloop in order to go through all of the files in my test folder", you can use cfdirectory on that folder.  It will return a ColdFusion query through which you can loop.

The rest of your code looks more complicated than it needs to be.  Reading the spreadsheet gives you a query object - so far so good.

Your database query, named contact looks supicious.  You refer to a variable named res but it's not clear where that comes from.  If it comes from the spreadsheet, then a value list might be more appropriate.  By the way, use query parameters.

It seems you want your csv file to combine data from the spreadsheet and the database query.  If that's the case, a query of queries might be useful.

If it were me, I'd use cffile action="write" to create my csv file.  I would also surround each value with double quotes in case any of them contained commas.